# useEffect causing it to call the method to get posts way too many times. I only want to get the posts when my query changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect, reddit

I am trying to call the reddit API. The post titles are showing up, but I want them to rerender when my query changes. I just want to know how to call a method when a piece of my state changes(aka my query). I’m using useEffect from react to do it but that calls it whenever anything changes in the component, causing it to call the method to get posts way to many times. I only want to get the posts when my query changes.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

function Results()
{   
    const query = useSelector(state => state.query);
    const results = useSelector(state => state.results);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let fetchResults = () =>
    {
        let postTitles = [];
        let postSrcs = [];

        fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/' + query + '.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(body => {
            for (let i = 0; i < body.data.children.length; ++i) {
                if (body.data.children[i].data.post_hint === 'image')
                {
                    let img_url = body.data.children[i].data.url_overridden_by_dest;
                    postSrcs.push(img_url);
                }
                let title = body.data.children[i].data.title;
                postTitles.push(title);
            }
            dispatch({type: "QUERY_RESULTS", payload: postTitles})
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchResults();
        console.log("use effect triggered")
    })
    
  

    return (
        <>
        <h1>Query: {query}</h1>
        
        { !results 
        ? <h1>No Results</h1> 
        : results.map(p => <h6> {p} </h6>)
        }

        </>
    )
}

export default Results;
```

For example in the console log that tells me when use effect is triggered. and when i search for a post the use effect triggered is stacking up.

Comment: You have not specified a dependency array for your useEffect, so it runs on every render. Add the variable that should trigger the useEffect to the dependency array. `useEffect(() => {fetchResults();}, [query]);` see: [Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

Comment: Add the state variable [you want to check as a dependency to the effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html): `useEffect(() => code, [myVar]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect has a differents mode. You can check how to use in official document https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

So the main you must know is 3 things

1. useEffect is the last render in react. So first render a components and read other code when it finish useEffect run.
2. useEffect may run code only one time adding []. for example

```
useEffect ( () => {
 ...code
}, [])
```

This code will run only one time.

3. useEffect may run code watching variables adding variables into []. For example

```
useEffect ( () => {
 ...code
}, [ count, name , ... ])
```

This code will run first time and later would run if count or name change

Answer (score 0):

Hooks like useEffect are used in function components. The Class component comparison to useEffect are the methods componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount.

useEffect will run when the component renders, which might be more times than you think.

So useEffect takes a second parameter
The second param is an array of variables that the component will check to make sure changed before re-rendering. You could put whatever bits of props and state you want in here to check against.

In your case add [query] as a second para:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        fetchResults();
        console.log("use effect triggered")
    },[query])
```

https://css-tricks.com/run-useeffect-only-once/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need to prevent `useEffect` to be called on any changes, and only once the `query` changes.

NOTE: Since you're using `dispatch` within `fetchResults`, it's better to make sure that `dispatch` is ready before calling `fetchResults`.

Your `useEffect` may look like the following to achieve that:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // To prevent call fetchResults if dispatch only is changed
  if (query) {
    fetchResults();
    console.log("use effect triggered");
  }
}, [dispatch, query]);
```